# Cant install VMware ESXi complete update 1 on ESXi 5.1 via update manager

Tags: vmware, esxi

I've updated a couple of hosts, one worked and one didn't. Both of these hosts are the same model and have the same ESXi version and required the same updates. the first host happily installed all the updates in two attempts (as I installed updates then a few new hp moduels).
However the second host refused to install the VMware ESXi complete update 1.

I tried a staged approach which potential caused the issue on the second host but I have no idea how to fix it or even if this was the cause.

Vsphere doesn't give much information on this but it shows "The host returns esxupdate error code:15. The package manager transaction is not successful. Check the update manager logs and esxupdate log files for more details"

I cant see anything useful in the update manager logs.

Below is part of the esxiupdate.log file the update section that contains errors.

```
        Command: update
Args: ['update']
Options: {'nosigcheck': None, 'retry': 3, 'loglevel': None, 'cleancache': None, 'viburls': ['http://x.x.x.x:9084/vum/repository/hostupdate/vmw/vib20/tools-light/VMware_locker_tools-light_5.1.0-1.12.1065491.vib'], 'meta': ['http://x.x.x.x:9084/vum/repository/hostupdate/HPQ/metadata-hp-HPUtil-esxi5.0-bundle-1.5-31_1380888545.zip', 'http://x.x.x.x:9084/vum/repository/hostupdate/HPQ/metadata-hp-esxi5.0uX-bundle-1.3.5-3_1380888952.zip', 'http://x.x.x.x:9084/vum/repository/hostupdate/HPQ/metadata-hp-esxi5.0uX-bundle-1.4-16_1380888514.zip', 'http://x.x.x.x:9084/vum/repository/hostupdate/csco/csco-VEM-5.1.0-metadata.zip', 'http://x.x.x.x:9084/vum/repository/hostupdate/vmw/vmw-ESXi-5.1.0-metadata.zip'], 'proxyurl': None, 'timeout': 30.0, 'cachesize': None, 'hamode': True, 'maintenancemode': True}
2013-10-16T19:10:32Z esxupdate: vmware.runcommand: INFO: runcommand called with: args = '['/sbin/bootOption', '-rp']', outfile = 'None', returnoutput = 'True', timeout = '0.0'.
2013-10-16T19:10:32Z esxupdate: vmware.runcommand: INFO: runcommand called with: args = '['/sbin/bootOption', '-ro']', outfile = 'None', returnoutput = 'True', timeout = '0.0'.
2013-10-16T19:10:32Z esxupdate: vmware.runcommand: INFO: runcommand called with: args = '['/sbin/esxcfg-advcfg', '-U', 'host-acceptance-level', '-G']', outfile = 'None', returnoutput = 'True', timeout = '0.0'.
2013-10-16T19:10:32Z esxupdate: downloader: DEBUG: Downloading from http://x.x.x.x:9084/vum/repository/hostupdate/vmw/vib20/tools-light/VMware_locker_tools-light_5.1.0-1.12.1065491.vib...
2013-10-16T19:10:32Z esxupdate: Transaction: INFO: Skipping installed VIBs
2013-10-16T19:10:32Z esxupdate: Transaction: INFO: Final list of VIBs being installed: VMware_locker_tools-light_5.1.0-1.12.1065491
2013-10-16T19:10:32Z esxupdate: imageprofile: INFO: Adding VIB VMware_locker_tools-light_5.1.0-1.12.1065491 to ImageProfile (Updated) ESXi-5.1.0-799733-standard
2013-10-16T19:10:32Z esxupdate: HostImage: DEBUG: Staging image profile [(Updated) ESXi-5.1.0-799733-standard]
2013-10-16T19:10:32Z esxupdate: HostImage: DEBUG: VIBs in image profile: VMware_bootbank_net-e1000e_1.1.2-3vmw.510.1.12.1065491, VMware_bootbank_scsi-bnx2i_1.9.1d.v50.1-5vmw.510.0.0.799733, VMware_bootbank_sata-sata-promise_2.12-3vmw.510.0.0.799733, Hewlett-Packard_bootbank_hp-smx-provider_500.03.02.00.23-434156, VMware_bootbank_net-sky2_1.20-2vmw.510.0.0.799733, VMware_bootbank_scsi-fnic_1.5.0.3-1vmw.510.0.0.799733, VMware_bootbank_misc-cnic-register_1.1-1vmw.510.0.0.799733, VMware_bootbank_esx-xlibs_5.1.0-0.0.799733, VMware_bootbank_scsi-megaraid-mbox_2.20.5.1-6vmw.510.0.0.799733, Hewlett-Packard_bootbank_hptestevent_5.0.0.01-00.00.4.434156, VMware_bootbank_scsi-ips_7.12.05-4vmw.510.0.0.799733, VMware_bootbank_sata-ahci_3.0-13vmw.510.0.0.799733, VMware_bootbank_sata-sata-svw_2.3-3vmw.510.0.0.799733, VMware_bootbank_scsi-qla4xxx_5.01.03.2-4vmw.510.0.0.799733, VMware_bootbank_net-cnic_1.10.2j.v50.7-3vmw.510.0.0.799733, VMware_bootbank_net-e1000_8.0.3.1-2vmw.510.0.0.799733, VMware_bootbank_ata-pata-serverworks_0.4.3-3vmw.510.0
2013-10-16T19:10:32Z esxupdate: vmware.runcommand: INFO: runcommand called with: args = '['/usr/sbin/vsish', '-e', '-p', 'cat', '/hardware/bios/dmiInfo']', outfile = 'None', returnoutput = 'True', timeout = '0.0'.
2013-10-16T19:10:32Z esxupdate: imageprofile: DEBUG: VIB VMware_locker_tools-light_5.1.0-1.12.1065491 is being removed from ImageProfile (Updated) ESXi-5.1.0-799733-standard
2013-10-16T19:10:32Z esxupdate: HostImage: INFO: Nothing for LiveImageInstaller to do, skipping.
2013-10-16T19:10:32Z esxupdate: imageprofile: DEBUG: VIB VMware_locker_tools-light_5.1.0-1.12.1065491 is being removed from ImageProfile (Updated) ESXi-5.1.0-799733-standard
2013-10-16T19:10:32Z esxupdate: HostImage: INFO: Nothing for BootBankInstaller to do, skipping.
2013-10-16T19:10:32Z esxupdate: HostImage: DEBUG:  --- Stage: LockerInstaller adding [VMware_locker_tools-light_5.1.0-1.12.1065491], removing []
2013-10-16T19:10:32Z esxupdate: HostImage: INFO: Attempting to download VIB tools-light
2013-10-16T19:10:32Z esxupdate: downloader: DEBUG: Downloading from http://x.x.x.x:9084/vum/repository/hostupdate/vmw/vib20/tools-light/VMware_locker_tools-light_5.1.0-1.12.1065491.vib...
2013-10-16T19:10:34Z esxupdate: esxupdate: ERROR: An esxupdate error exception was caught:
2013-10-16T19:10:34Z esxupdate: esxupdate: ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
2013-10-16T19:10:34Z esxupdate: esxupdate: ERROR:   File "/usr/sbin/esxupdate", line 216, in main
2013-10-16T19:10:34Z esxupdate: esxupdate: ERROR:     cmd.Run()
2013-10-16T19:10:34Z esxupdate: esxupdate: ERROR:   File "/build/mts/release/bora-1065491/bora/build/esx/release/vmvisor/sys/lib/python2.6/site-packages/vmware/esx5update/Cmdline.py", line 144, in Run
2013-10-16T19:10:34Z esxupdate: esxupdate: ERROR:   File "/build/mts/release/bora-1065491/bora/build/esx/release/vmvisor/sys/lib/python2.6/site-packages/vmware/esximage/Transaction.py", line 243, in InstallVibsFromSources
2013-10-16T19:10:34Z esxupdate: esxupdate: ERROR:   File "/build/mts/release/bora-1065491/bora/build/esx/release/vmvisor/sys/lib/python2.6/site-packages/vmware/esximage/Transaction.py", line 345, in _installVibs
2013-10-16T19:10:34Z esxupdate: esxupdate: ERROR:   File "/build/mts/release/bora-1065491/bora/build/esx/release/vmvisor/sys/lib/python2.6/site-packages/vmware/esximage/Transaction.py", line 388, in _validateAndInstallProfile
2013-10-16T19:10:34Z esxupdate: esxupdate: ERROR:   File "/build/mts/release/bora-1065491/bora/build/esx/release/vmvisor/sys/lib/python2.6/site-packages/vmware/esximage/HostImage.py", line 677, in Stage
2013-10-16T19:10:34Z esxupdate: esxupdate: ERROR:   File "/build/mts/release/bora-1065491/bora/build/esx/release/vmvisor/sys/lib/python2.6/site-packages/vmware/esximage/HostImage.py", line 463, in _download_and_stage
2013-10-16T19:10:34Z esxupdate: esxupdate: ERROR: InstallationError: ('VMware_locker_tools-light_5.1.0-1.12.1065491', '[Errno 32] Broken pipe')
2013-10-16T19:10:34Z esxupdate: esxupdate: DEBUG: <<<
2013-10-16T19:10:38Z esxupdate: vmware.runcommand: INFO: runcommand called with: args = '['/sbin/esxcfg-advcfg', '-q', '-g', '/UserVars/EsximageNetTimeout']', outfile = 'None', returnoutput = 'True', timeout = '0.0'.
2013-10-16T19:10:38Z esxupdate: vmware.runcommand: INFO: runcommand called with: args = '['/sbin/esxcfg-advcfg', '-q', '-g', '/UserVars/EsximageNetRetries']', outfile = 'None', returnoutput = 'True', timeout = '0.0'.
2013-10-16T19:10:38Z esxupdate: vmware.runcommand: INFO: runcommand called with: args = '['/sbin/esxcfg-advcfg', '-q', '-g', '/UserVars/EsximageNetRateLimit']', outfile = 'None', returnoutput = 'True', timeout = '0.0'.
2013-10-16T19:10:38Z esxupdate: esxupdate: INFO: ---
```

Comment: I have done some more investigation on this and have tried the following. http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/395840-esxi-5-1-complete-update-1-via-baseline-gone-wrong-please-help and http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2006034 suggests to remove the FDM vib, this has not helped. Removing the contents of the /var/core and retrying the upgrade, also no use as the folder is already empty

Comment: while trying this http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2030665 I discovered some things. while trying to copy the files using winscp it comes up saying insufficient space. Also looking at the folder structure and comparing it to the working host there is a short cut in the root to locker (on the working host) this takes me to the /vmfs/volumes/efd8efe3-03bc1cbf-15e0-080efd9e7379 where as on the host that isn't updating the locker folder in the root is not a shortcut.

Comment: Ive also noticed that the healthy server has a shortcut in the root to product locker where as the host that wont update is missing this shortcut in the root, is this anything to do with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is a probably a network problem, if not then a disk problem. Simply retry.